# Error updating data from form in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to update my data using this form, however I am getting an error:

[image: The webform]
 **my controller:**

```
public function update($id)
{
    $dosenUpdate = Request::all();
    $dosen = Dosen::find($id);
    $dosen->update($dosenUpdate);
    return redirect('dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil dirubah!');
}

public function status()
{
    $dosen = \App\Dosen::paginate(5);
    return view('dosen.status', compact('dosen'));
}
```

**my route:**

```
Route::get('/dosen/status', 'DosenController@status');
```

**my view:**

```
{!! Form::model($dosen, ['route' => ['dosen.update', $dosen->id] !!}
 {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') !!}
 {!! Form::select('status', array('1' => 'Ready', '0' => 'Not Ready'), null, ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Status'], ['class' => 'form-control'], ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Status']) !!}
 {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Save', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'] )  }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**The error response:**

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id (View:       
D:\XAMPP\htdocs\infodosen\resources\views\dosen\status.blade.php)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is my_view is status_blade.php ??

Answer (score 1):

You are triyng to get a property from a collection of objects ( LengthAwarePaginator ).

To get the id of model Dosen in your view, you must iterate the collection.

Something like this:

```
@foreach($dosen as $d)
  {!! Form::model($d, ['route' => ['dosen.update', $d->id] !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') !!}
    {!! Form::select('status', array('1' => 'Ready', '0' => 'Not Ready'), null, ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Status'], ['class' => 'form-control'], ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Status']) !!}
    {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Save', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'] )  }}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

If you get a TokenMismatch error, be sure to include your routes inside the Route group with the middleware called 'web'.

For example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
//put your routes here
}
```

This will take care also of the error where your $error variable is unset inside your views

Comment: it's worked. but when i click save i got error :     

   TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67
@RDev

Comment: is that a ajax call for save?

Comment: no. i try add `@if ($errors->any())
                                <ul class="alert alert-danger">
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            @endif  `


and i got error : Undefined variable: errors
@RDev

Comment: Make sure that the route that is pointing to the view with that error is inside the middleware called 'web'.
Otherwise the variable $errors will not be set.
That route group is present in all laravel 5.2 fresh installation: 
`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //your route here
}`

Be sure to add also the route that gives you the token mismatch error. This is why you get also that error

Comment: I updated my answer to take care of those errors too